# I logged out of the main site but I am not logged out of chat

Tags: support, chat, login

Whenever I log in to stackoverflow, It has my username and the opportunity to log-out.

But as soon as I click the chat link, the user name changes to some other user name, and worst of all, there is no logout option.

What can I do?

Comment: were you on `chat.stackexchange` or `chat.stackoverflow` because there is a BIG difference between those URLs. Look closely...

Comment: @JeffAtwood http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can log out at https://chat.stackexchange.com/logout. The Stack Overflow chat needs no logout link, since you can just log out of Stack Overflow and will be logged out of chat automatically, but the Stack Exchange chat login isn't tied to a particular site, so that doesn't work.

We should probably show this link somewhere on https://chat.stackexchange.com; the functionality is there, but you're right, it's not really exposed anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem. my guess is that someone else used this computer before . I tried to log out - but did not find where to do that . anyhow , for a long time now I found that the login / logout procedures of the whole network are not so solid . Sometimes flipping sites gives me tottally unexpected results .

Comment: Just a clarification : logging out of Stack Overflow was NOT enough . clicking on the http://chat.stackexchange.com/logout link was the answer .

Comment: That's what I said -- to log out of chat.stackoverflow.com, you just log out of stackoverflow.com; to log out of chat.stackexchange.com, that's not enough.

Comment: right .. but there is no link to be found :-)